# Liferay DXP: Setting/Disabling User Registration fields

Tags: liferay, taglib, liferay-7

I chose to *disable* some of the fields used in Liferays' user-registration with the help of `language.properties` and `portal-ext.properties` which is working fine so far.
It seems that there is no option/field to disable or hide the 'Language' selector, so I figured I will need to write my own login-portlet or hook the existing one.
The latter is more preferrable to me, so I hooked `create_account.jsp`.

Where I would expect the language selector to be, there is only this tag which seems to be a composite component that I cannot configure to my needs:

```
<liferay-ui:user-name-fields />
```

Do I have to write my own taglib component to achieve this or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution here is to create your own registration portlet: it's very easy to develop and you can use just the fields you need. Any other solution is more complex and less maintainable.

Comment: It's sad they mixed so many things up instead of keeping granularity. In the end, you better re-do everything liferay has to offer...